# How to hide warning when working with apptainer

Tags: docker, singularity-container, apptainer

This is the code:

```
## The tools are images generated and excuted by apptainer
export python="apptainer run /mainfs/wrgl/broadinstitute_warp_development/warp/images/datascience-notebook_latest.sif"
logmessage "INFO: apptainer images were detected"


## run python script to generate (i) samples_list (ii) run JSON file (ii) per sample json file
$python python samplesheet ${path}/SampleSheetUsed.csv
```

And this gives me a warning I don't care (or I think I should care).

```
[WARN  tini (239863)] Tini is not running as PID 1 and isn't registered as a child subreaper.
Zombie processes will not be re-parented to Tini, so zombie reaping won't work.
To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1.
```

How can I hide this? I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the solutions provided in the warning. Setting the env variable in the definition file is probably sufficient;

```
%environment
    TINI_SUBREAPER=true
```